# Slowing down animation speed in matplotlib python

Tags: python, animation, recursion, matplotlib, global-variables

I have small question, I am making animation in **matplotlib** and I am using **rotate_deg_around()** function. My problem is that I need rotate my object, **remember** its position, and in next step rotate this rotated object etc. My idea was that I make **global variable** in which I store actual data (variable ghost), and I will update it with my drawing method (drawMyObjects()), using next method updateGhost(). 
My problem is, that speed of the animation is going down, it is **slower and slower**.And on the end it **freeze**. 
What do you think, where should be a problem? I tried check memory, it looks allright.
When I rotate oroginal object, it works pretty well (when I don`t need to remember new rotated data)
My problem is in simple method **updateGhost()**, because without useing it, it works well, but not in way which I need.
A will appreciate your help, thank you all.
EDIT 1: when it runs longer time: **RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded** do not know why ...

```
def init():
line.set_data([], [])
return line,

ghost = ax.transData

def updateGhost(u):
    global ghost
    ghost=u

def drawMyObjects(i):

    global ghost

    td2dis = ax.transData
    td2dis2=ghost

    #1st Object
    radius=getOnlyRadius(f1,f2)
    rox,roy=setRotatePoint(radius,True)
    coords = td2dis.transform([rox,roy]) 
    tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords[0], coords[1], 50*i/radius) 
    t = td2dis + tr

    #2nd Object
    radius2=radius+randomError(radius);
    rox2,roy2=setRotatePoint(radius2,True)
    coords2 = duch.transform([rox2,roy2]) 
    tr2 = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(coords2[0], coords2[1], 1.5) 
    u = td2dis2 + tr2
    updateGhost(u)#it updates transData because I need to remember last position of my object

    robotBody = patches.Rectangle((x,y),sirkaRobota,dlzkaRobota,color='black',alpha=0.5,transform=t)
    ax.add_patch(robotBody)
    robotBody2 = patches.Rectangle((x,y),sirkaRobota,dlzkaRobota,color='black',alpha=0.1,transform=u)
    ax.add_patch(robotBody2)
    return robotBody,robotBody2


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, drawMyObjects, frames=10000,init_func=init, interval=20, blit=True)
```

Comment: You are adding new artists, but never removing or deleting the old ones.

Comment: Thanks for reaction @tcaswell . Do you have any idea how to remove/delete them? I tried this: plt.cla() plt.clf() OR robotBody.remove() but it didn`t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were 2 main problems:

1.) I use recursion to count matrixes (processor kill)

2.) I didnt remove added lines (memory kill)